# Html form returns null?

Tags: php, twig

I try to learn php/twig from a tutorial video and I tried to recreate the exercise but can't get back data from a simple form. The name variable in the action is always null. Everything else works. I looked through it multiple times but did everything like in the video. Some help would be really appreciated, thank you!

The action:

```
      public function AddAction(Request $request) : Response{
        $name = $request->request->get("name");  //always null
        if ($name){
            file_put_contents($this->fname, $name,FILE_APPEND);
            $this->addFlash("notice","ITEM ADDED");
        }
        else{
            $this->addFlash("notice","DATA ERROR");
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute("list");
    }
```

The form:

```
{% block body %}
    <form action="{{ path('add') }}" mehod="POST">
        <table>
        <tr><td>Name of new item:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="SEND"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is `$request->request>-get()` correct? Shouldn't that be `$request->get()`? Try dumping `$request` to see what it contains

Comment: Also, `mehod` should be `method`

Comment: Ty, that was it!